# Validate form, check if user exists, register them. All with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, if-statement

My javascript is inside an html file called register.html.
The user submits the form. This should then trigger the `$('input[name="createacc"]').click(function (e)` AJAX then sends those 4 variables to checkuser.php. Checkuser.php should then check to see if the username exists. If it does exist, it should echo 0. If it does not exists, it should echo 1. Register.html then checks to see what checkuser.php echoed. If the echo was "0" then, then an alert box should appear saying username unavailable. If the echo was "1" or anything else, register.html should run `$("#registerform").submit();` which then does the php script. This should all happen without leaving the register.html page.

**I check chrome's built in debugger and I see that if the account exists checkuser.php writes back 0 and if the account doesn't it writes back 1. But for some reason nothing else happens. The account does not register nor do I get an alert box saying the username is unavailable**

here is my register.html

```
<form ata-parsley-validate name="registerform" id="registerform" action="register.php" method="post">

                        <p>
                            <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
                            <input name="firstname" id="firstname" maxlength="32" type="text" placeholder="Optional" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="username" id="usernameText">Username:</label>
                            <input data-parsley-pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9_]{3,15}$" data-parsley-length="[3, 15]" name="username" id="username" maxlength="32" type="text" data-parsley-error-message="Username needs to be between 3 and 15 characters. Case sensitive. No special characters allowed." required/>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="password1">Password:</label>
                            <input name="password1" id="password1" data-parsley-pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9_-]{5,25}$" data-parsley-length="[5, 25]" type="password" data-parsley-equalto="#password2" data-parsley-error-message="Passwords must match. Needs to be between 5 and 25 characters. Case sensitive. No special characters allowed." required/>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="password2">Confirm Your Password:</label>
                            <input name="password2" id="password2" data-parsley-length="[5, 25]" data-parsley-error-message="Passwords must match. Needs to be between 5 and 25 characters. Case sensitive. No special characters allowed." data-parsley-pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9_-]{5,25}$" type="password" data-parsley-equalto="#password1" required/>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="email">E-Mail:</label>
                            <input data-parsley-trigger="change" name="email" id="email" maxlength="1024" type="email" required/>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <input type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" name="createacc" value="Register" />
                        </p>
                    </form>
```

Here is my javascript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


    $('input[name="createacc"]').click(function (e) {
        var username = $('input[name="username"]').val();
        var firstname = $('input[name="firstname"]').val();
        var password1 = $('input[name="password1"]').val();
        var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
        e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                username: username,
                firstname: firstname,
                password1: password1,
                email: email
            },
            url: 'checkuser.php',
            success: function (data) { //Receives the data from the php code
                if (data === "0") {
                    alert("Username Unavailable");
                } else {
                   $("#registerform").submit();
                alert("Account successfuly created"); 
                }


            },
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

        });
</script>
```

**Update - I have fixed parts of my code through the help of others below me. My only issue now is that `$("#registerform").submit();` doesn't do anything**

Comment: Can you can check in chrome debugger "Network" tab. There should be your request with all it's stuff including the response and response code

Comment: I think because you have submitted the form before the click event runs.

Comment: @steveniseki I believe that is what the `e.preventDefault();` is there for?

Comment: @damienix https://i.imgur.com/J7w9NoC.png That is if the username exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to return and JSON not setting

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Decide whether you want to pass plaintext or json. Your string might be now **"0"**, not **0**

Try

```
if (data === '"0"') {
```

Comment: That helped. But now no matter if the username exists or not, I get a popup saying "Username Unavailable"

Comment: So what helped exactly and in what way helped if it's still not working? ;)

Comment: Maybe just return plaintext and check 0/1 instead of awkward "0"/"1"

Comment: Okay so I changed it to `if (data === '"0"') {` and now if the username already exists, I get an alert saying "Username Unavailable". and if the username does not exist, it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I know the else code works because i added a                   `alert("Account successfuly created");` to it but it doesn't seem to be registering

Comment: BTW, it's that inverted behaveiour of your if

Comment: 1. Put break point in chrome debugger in line **if (data === "0") {** and check what it does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66839/discussion-between-damienix-and-dgameman1).

Comment: I've realized the issue is with the $("#registerform").submit(); not doing it's job

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form then?

Comment: I changed it to `$("#registerform").ajaxForm({url: 'register.php', type: 'post'})` but the console gives me an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: You don't have ajaxForm plugin. Include the plugin or use the latter solution with $.post()

Comment: Oh my god. It works. You're honestly amazing. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your success.you have written If it does exist, it should echo 0. If it does not exists, it should echo 1.you should use:

```
success: function (data) { //Receives the data from the php code
                if (data == '"0"') {       //register if user exists.          
                $("#registerform").submit();
                } else {
                      alert("Username Unavailable");
                }
```

Comment: That helped. But now no matter if the username exists or not, I get a popup saying "Username Unavailable"

Comment: The php code returns codes differently, so OP should revert that to be consistent with internet, but its not that bug here.

Comment: just do console.log(data) and see what it gives.

Comment: I'm further now that I changed it to `if (data === '"0"') {`. Look up at  damienix comments

Comment: I've realized the issue is with the $("#registerform").submit(); not doing it's job